# Docker with more than one docker container not working azure

Tags: node.js, apache, azure, docker

We are trying to create and update a docker image into an azure container registry, for an azure webapp with nodejs and apache.
I know only 443 and 80 ports are open on these webapps and i am trying to output apache through 443 and nodejs through 80.
I am using the following dockerfile

```
#Dockerfile

FROM php:5.6-apache
RUN apt-get update
COPY src/ /var/www/html/
RUN a2enmod rewrite
RUN service apache2  restart

FROM node:7
WORKDIR /app
COPY nodeapp/package.json /app
RUN npm install
COPY nodeapp/ /app
CMD node /app/server.js
EXPOSE 3000 80
```

The docker image was build and successfully uploaded into the container registry, But it is not working.Both Apache and node are not working.
Is there any wrong with this ? or any other method is available to achive this?

Comment: Do you have error you got?

Comment: @Edmhs No,I am new in using azure and docker. Where can we find its error logs?

Comment: What do you mean by "But it is not working. Both Apache and node are not working"?  What Azure service are you using to run your containers?

Comment: @CSharpRocks Both are not working,i m using app service with web app

Comment: What is the configuration when you create the two web apps?

Comment: Maybe you can check which port does the service listen to. And if the ports that you expose are right.